# Where to find Thunderbird profile in macOS Sierra10.12.6?

Tags: thunderbird, macbook, transfer, profile

I've used Thunderbird for ~7 years on a MacBook Air, which is now running macOS Sierra 10.12.6.  The present Thunderbird version on that machine is 68.11.0.  I am in the process of moving from that MacBook to a Dell laptop.

For security reasons, I'm not allowed to use Thunderbird any more to check email on my work account, but I can use Thunderbird on the new machine to store/access the old messages of that account.  This means I need to transfer my existing Thunderbird messages to Thunderbird on the new laptop, in order to be able to access them as an archive.

I've looked at several references that say I can do this by copying my existing Thunderbird profile from the MacBook, and then pasting it into Thunderbird on the Dell.  Those sources also say that my Thunderbird profile on the MacBook should be found at MacHD-Users-myusername-Library. When I follow that path using Finder, though, there is no folder labeled Library -- the only folders under my username are Applications, Box, Downloads, Creative Cloud, Movies, Music, Pictures, and Public.

Within Thunderbird on the MacBook, I have followed Help-Troubleshooting Information to a list labeled Application Basics, and found a row labeled Profile Folder, with a button that then shows me a folder labeled XYZABC.default (not the real folder name, but it does have the suffix default).  When I tried to copy that folder onto a thumb drive -- which has more space available than the size listed for the profile folder -- I get an error message of "the item XYZABC.default can't be copied because it is too large for the volume's format"

So I have 2 questions:

1. is the folder I've found through the path Help-Troubleshooting Information the Thunderbird profile I want to transfer to the new machine?  If not, where do I find the correct profile?

and

2. How can I do a physical copy/transfer of the correct profile?
   Thanks for any advice you can give.

Comment: The profile folder is indicated in *Help > Troubleshooting Information* and should look like `~/Library/Thunderbird/Profiles/xxxxxxxx.default/`. Can't you see it? Or is it hidden?

Comment: @harrymc -- the profile folder I'm directed to has the path  MacHD/Users/myusername/Library/Thunderbird/Profiles/xxxxxxxx.default         But this is the folder I've been unable to copy onto a thumbdrive or external hard drive, when I use the standard Copy key commands.

Comment: I think that you have a problem with permissions. Try to copy as root (sudo).

Comment: @harrymc --  Although I couldn't see my Library going directly through Finder, I was able to see my Library by backing in -- used Troubleshooting Info from Thunderbird to locate the profile folder, then backed in by using the "Enclosing Folder" command several times.  Bottom line -- I got the profile copied onto an external HD (after using a converter app to adjust for formatting on the HD), have transferred it to the new machine, and can now open Thunderbird on the new machine and see my old messages.   Thanks much for your help.